# What happens to the host's body when a tailed beast is extracted?

Tags: naruto

I heard from someone that the host's chest and heart start to disintegrate when a tailed beast is extracted.

Is that true?

Comment: What do you think happened to Gaara after his tailed beast was extracted?

Comment: Gaara was unconscious when Shukaku was being extracted, and died once the ritual completed. He was then revived by Lady Chiyo at the expense of her own life.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, when a tailed beast is extracted, the host dies. It's an obvious fact in the Narutoverse.

But in cases where the host, or the jinchuriki, is a member of the Uzumaki clan, they will still be alive. This is because of the extreme tenacity of the Uzumaki clan.

Comment: Second paragraph - source please.

Answer (score -2):

As shown in the final war arc, when Madara was stripped off all the tailed beasts, the user slowly starts dying within a few minutes of the extraction. This is one of the two known moments where a person is shown dying post-extraction.

The other one was Gaara, but I think he was left unconscious and then died post-extraction.

Kushina was killed by Kyubi although she was going to die anyway.

As someone mentioned earlier, people with huge chakra reserves themselves can keep themselves alive for a few more minutes but will eventually die.

Comment: Kushina I believe was weakened after extraction, but still had enough strength to help Minato seal Kurama. Her heritage as an Uzumaki gave her immense vitality. She dies due to being impaled by Kurama.